# Playframework 2 java iterate map in template

Tags: loops, dictionary, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new in playframework 2 and I would like to iterate a map in the template, I'm using java for the moment :-)
Can anybody, please, write a example ?
My map is like :

```
Map<Integer,MyObject>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15):

In a Play 2 template, you can iterate on a map using this syntax :

```
@(myMap: Map[Integer, MyObject])

@for((key, value) <- myMap){
  @key - @value
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Thank a lot for your answer @mguillermin.
I found other thing that can help somebody, to use the current index in the loop :

```
@for(((key, value), currentIndex) <- myMap.zipWithIndex) {
  @key - @value - @currentIndex
}
```